# Play SoundCloud Track

Tags: android, soundcloud

can i play a track from SoundCloud in my android app? I'm trying this code but it doesn't works:

```
String res = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/84973999/stream?client_id=cd9d2e5604410d714e32642a4ec0eed4";

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
try {
        mp.setDataSource(res);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: my logcat: 03-31 11:10:26.160: E/MediaPlayer(1780): error (1, -4)
03-31 11:10:26.710: I/MediaPlayer(1780): Info (1,26)

Comment: -4 error means an invalid argument.

Comment: Is there another way?

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem trying to play a Soundcloud stream from Android.

What fixed it for me was adding the following permissions to my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

For me it was a facepalm moment. Here is my mediaplayer implementation.

For my mediaplayer I have a class that implements

```
MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
```

And in that class I use the following code to setup the MediaPlayer.

```
 mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
 mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try{
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/7399237/stream?client_id=XXX");
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

And in my `onPrepared` callback I simply start playing the stream.

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: crashes on prepareAsync(); . IllegalStateException. ?

Answer (score 0):

trying adding this before you set data source

```
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

there have also been issues noted when using MediaPlayer with URL redirects. You may need to resolve the redirects first, then set your datasource accordingly

To get the redirected url you can do soemthing like this using the [soundcloud java-api-wrapper](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper)

```
HttpResponse resp = wrapper.get(Request.to(res));
if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) {
    final Header location = resp.getFirstHeader("Location");
    if (location != null && location.getValue() != null) {
        String redirectedStream = location.getValue();
        //...
    }
}
```