# Android media player error(1, -1004) while playing a stream from external website

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play an audio file from a website in my android App but it encounters media player error(1, -1004).

The streaming link is working fine when i use it in windows media player or vlc player. why android media player is generating this error? my code is

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_file);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

     playSong("http://WEBSITE/001.mp3");
}

private void playSong(String songPath) {
    MediaPlayer mP = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mP.setDataSource(songPath);
        mP.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mP.prepare();
        mP.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.start();

            }
        });

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: have you scene my updated answer?? please look

Comment: hi if problem is solved than accept the answer ans raise pts that we can move to solve next question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Below Code

```
MediaPlayer mP = new MediaPlayer();
        mP.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mP.setDataSource(songPath);
            mP.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mP.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mP.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: where did you add mp.start();

Comment: in the overridenn method of onPrepared as follows :@Override
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer play) {
  if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
   progressDialog.dismiss();
  }
  play.start();
 }

Answer (score 0):

This may be the solution:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<use-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Thanks to this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17911777/1193534