# Android MediaPlayer Error -1004

Tags: java, android, media-player, onclicklistener

I'm having a problem with the MediaPlayer. This is in a `SherlockFragment` and it worked when I created buttons using XML.

The working code looked like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.stop:
        if(mPlayer!=null && mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mPlayer.stop();
            buttonPlay.setText("Play");
            mPlayer.reset();
            buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.play:
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
        buttonPlay.setText("Playing...");
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mPlayer.setDataSource(url); error 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mPlayer.setDataSource(url); error 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mPlayer.setDataSource(url); error 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mPlayer.prepareAsync();  
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Fetching files...");
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {  
                //Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                mp.start();  
            }  
        });
        break;
    }
}
```

It worked fine but I need it to working for programmatically created buttons like this:

```
           play[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("button", "play clicked ");
                    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try {
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mPlayer.setDataSource(url); error 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mPlayer.setDataSource(url); error 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mPlayer.setDataSource(url); error 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    play[a].setText("Playing...");

                    for(int j =0; j < jsons.length; j++){
                        if(a != j ){
                            play[j].setEnabled(false);
                            stop[j].setEnabled(false);
                            Log.e("button", "making buttons false");
                        }
                    }

                    mPlayer.prepareAsync();  
                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog;
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Fetching files...");
                    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {  
                        @Override  
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {  
                            //Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            mp.start();  
                            Log.e("button", "playing ");
                        }  
                    });
                }
            });

            stop[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("button", "stop clicked ");
                }
            });
```

I'm getting this:

```
E/MediaPlayer(8362): error (1, -1004)
E/MediaPlayer(8362): Error (1,-1004)
```

`url = "http://******.******.ie/music/Mark%20Beswick%20-%20My%20Help.mp3";`

What I am doing wrong, please?

Btw I'm testing on a 4.1.1 Android, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Thanks to the first answer on this question - [Play SoundCloud Track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732553/play-soundcloud-track?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The error code 1004 bothered me in some devices too. Finally, I encoded the URL and solved it!

```
url = "http://******.******.ie/" + Uri.encode("music/Mark Beswick - My Help.mp3");
```